# python pandas aggregating non numeric types

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, aggregate

I have the following problem, I managed to create a data frame with object dtypes on some columns.
In particular these would be 2d numpy arrays but they could be any non-numeric type. Now I want to pivot my dataframe. Is there a way to pass an aggregating function of my choice which works on these objects? I don't seem to be able to do it and I get the error:

GroupByError: No numeric types to aggregate

For example, say I have this dummy data frame:

```
date foo  bar               mat
1     a   x      [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
1     b   x      [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
1     a   y      [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
1     b   y      [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
2     a   x      [[4, 5], [6, 7]]
2     b   x      [[4, 5], [6, 7]]
2     a   y      [[4, 5], [6, 7]]
2     b   y      [[4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

and I want to have a new data frame of the type:

```
dd.pivot_table(values=['mat'], rows=['date'], cols=['foo'], aggfunc= ??)
```

where my 2-d arrays will be an element-by-element sum of the arrays with same value in the 'foo' columns. How can I do that? If not possible, is it possible to pick the first occurrence of the 'mat' element in the list of arrays with same 'foo'? 
Thanks

added the desired output:

```
date    a               b           
1    [[2, 4], [6, 8]]  [[8, 10], [12, 14]]
2    [[2, 4], [6, 8]]  [[8, 10], [12, 14]]
```

Comment: please add example output

Comment: well, I get an error, so the output would be something like:     raise GroupByError('No numeric types to aggregate')
GroupByError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: I mean what do you want to get as output, resulting DataFrame

Comment: got it, it's there, basically summing up the 2-d arrays, but really it could be any aggregating function

Comment: This is not a very efficient representation of data. Have a look at multi-indexes, see: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex, or putting the 'mat' data in a separate data frame.

Answer (score 1):

You can group first and then pivot:

```
>>> grouped = df.groupby(('foo', 'date'))
>>> g = grouped['mat'].apply(lambda x: np.array(map(np.array, x.values)).T.sum(axis=2).T).reset_index()
>>> g
  foo  date                    0
0   a     1     [[2, 4], [6, 8]]
1   a     2  [[8, 10], [12, 14]]
2   b     1     [[2, 4], [6, 8]]
3   b     2  [[8, 10], [12, 14]]
>>> g.pivot(columns='foo', values=0, index='date').reset_index()
foo  date                    a                    b
0       1     [[2, 4], [6, 8]]     [[2, 4], [6, 8]]
1       2  [[8, 10], [12, 14]]  [[8, 10], [12, 14]]
```

To sum by elements I've used numpy sum over `axis=2` (converted lists into `np.array` beforehand). Also, seeems that your output is a bit incorrect - it should be:

```
date    a               b           
1    [[2, 4], [6, 8]]  [[8, 10], [12, 14]]
2    [[2, 4], [6, 8]]  [[8, 10], [12, 14]]
```

Comment: I think you should be able to use `sum(axis=0)` instead of `.T.sum(axis=2).T`.

Comment: ```import pandas as pd 
import sys,ast
input_str = sys.stdin.read()
input_list = ast.literal_eval(input_str)
cols=input_list[0]
values=input_list[1]
df=pd.read_csv('https://media-doselect.s3.amazonaws.com/generic/wkyk2AWYdJbqgXoRo3Y8w42nX/test.csv')
print(df.groupby(cols).get_group(tuple(values)).head()) ```